# Windows Batch file that uses lines from a file to construct arguments in a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, minify, google-closure-compiler, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

Need to use a large list of file names to construct an argument that goes to an application that is called from the Windows command line. I am trying to do this all from within a Windows Batch file.

So far I have this:

```
dir C:\javascripts /a-d /b /s >FileListing.txt
```

This creates a file called "FileListing.txt" whos contents look like this:

```
C:\javascripts\index.js
C:\javascripts\other_javascripts.js
...
C:\javascripts\helper.js
```

The next thing I need to do is call an executable that uses these file names as arguments in this way:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js=C:\javascripts\index.js 
                       --js=C:\javascripts\other_javascripts.js 
                       ... 
                       --js_output_file=compiled_javascripts.js
```

This is for use with the google javascript compiler. The objective is to take all these javascripts and minify and compile them into one file.

How do I get these file names into the command line arguments?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set JAVA_CMD=java -jar compilar.jar
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (FileListing.txt) do set JAVA_CMD=!JAVA_CMD! --js=%%f
set JAVA_CMD=!JAVA_CMD! --js_output_file=compiled_javascripts.js

:: Invoke the command
!JAVA_CMD!
```

Suggestion for improvement:
Lose the text file, and invoke the `dir` command from within the loop (note the omitted `/s`), like so:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir C:\javascripts /a-d /b') do set JAVA_CMD=!JAVA_CMD! --js=%%f
```

... the rest of the script stays the same.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Glad to help! Notice that I added the `"tokens=*"` to pull the entire line from the file. Otherwise it'll pull just the first word from each line (which is OK too, unless you have spaces in the filenames).