# batch to delete files that have their paths in a txt file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch that will delete files from a LAN, all the paths of the files being saved in a txt file. Don't know how the batch will "read" the paths then delete those files with `DEL` command.
The line that works so far is: 
`del "path\*.txt"` - for deletion of all txt in some folder (`path` being the actual line, like `c:\folder\folder\*.txt`), but I need for a lot more paths.
i pushed then the batch with psexec.exe (for the LAN deletion)

I guess it's 2-3 lines of code, but I'm new to batching & scripting, could someone pls help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FOR /F` command to process each line in your input file. Here is a SO answer: [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)
This just worked for me (the parentheses around the file name are necessary):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do del "%%A"
```

`myfile.txt` looks like this:

```
a.txt
b.txt
a b c.txt
```

Comment: so the text file that contains the paths look like (eg): c:\path\file1.pdf; second line is c:\path\file2.txt, and so on. Will the `for /f` loop through each file then where should I put the `del `command? (how should I write it?) @BubullC

Comment: something like this: `for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process] %%A` ? where [process] will be the del command? @BubullC

Comment: I included an example in my answer.

Comment: thanks! it worked!!! was wondering: If some file is currently being modified (someone works with it or just is open at the time of deletion), does the batch delete it after the user closes it?  thanks a lot again for your prompt answer @BubullC

Comment: thanks! it worked!!!  If some file is currently being modified (someone works with it or just is open at the time of deletion), the batch deletes it after the user closes it!!!  thanks a lot again for your prompt answer  Can I make the batch delete the files just after the user closes it? @BubullC

Comment: Depending on whether the program is blocking the file or not, the file gets either deleted immediately or not all all.

Answer (score 1):

```
del /s *.txt
```

`/s` means - delete from all subfolders..

or to iterate over directories:

```
for /d %i in (*.*) do del %i\*.exe
```

!!!) you should escape `%` with `%` if your code is in batch file