# copy files in a folder excluding some of them from a .txt file in windows

Tags: windows, macos, copy, delete-file

I have many images and json files which named as img-1 img-2...etc. in a folder, and I'd like to do copy them excluding some numbers in a txt file like:
100
1001
20345
or just copy all of them and delete these from the .txt
I　have windows7 and mac only and I don't know how to start with it since I found the command robotcopy. I know this question is kind of simple, but I need some hints to start .

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @user202729
I just found how stupid I was and wrote it in python by os.remove. Since I already opened this question I want to know how to do it in batch scripts in windows.

Comment: [Similar question answered here for batch script., Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307075/batch-to-delete-files-that-have-their-paths-in-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

python answer:
    import os
    count = 100000
    x = list(range(1,count+1))
        text_file = open("delete.txt", "r")
        del_imgs = text_file.readlines()
        for del_img in del_imgs:
            t=del_img.split("\n")
            img_path = "D:/images/img-"+t[0]+".bmp"
            json_path = "D:/images/img-"+t[0]+".json"
            os.remove(img_path)

by the way,which way would be faster? batch scripts or c &c++?