# Windows Batch File to Read textfile and append for pdftk

Tags: batch-file, pdftk

I have a text file which contains the location of a list of pdf files. I am writing a windows batch file that needs to read this line by line and append in a command which will be executed to merge all the pdfs into 1 pdf using pdftk.

Below is the example command:

```
pdftk "C:\test\1.pdf" "C:\test\2.pdf"......"C:\test\50.pdf" cat output merged.pdf
```

I came across this [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) for reading text file.

But how do I read and append to a variable which can then be used for the command mentioned above?

Comment: The reason i am doing this way is because I want the pdfs in an order. First to last. Is there a pdftk command to merge the pdfs in earliest to latest order based on time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your list of pdf files looks like this

```
pdf1.pdf
pdf2.pdf
pdf3.pdf
```

Then you can use this to concatenate them into one variable

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set files=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pdfs.txt) do (
if defined files (
set files=!files! "%%a"
) else (
set files="%%a"
)
)
pdftk !files! cat output merged.pdf
```

The `if else` is there to remove the leading space from the variable, I wasn't sure if that would make a difference. If it doesn't then you can get rid of it and just use

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set files=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (pdfs.txt) do (    
set files=!files! "%%a"
)
pdftk !files! cat output merged.pdf
```