# Parsing contents of file in CMD/Batch not working?

Tags: parsing, windows-7, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple text file with some numbers in it:

```
1122
2244
```

But when I run the CMD

```
FOR /F %i IN (CIFLIST.TXT) DO ECHO %i
```

Nothing is output to the screen?

I've also tried from a batch file as

```
FOR /F %%i IN (CIFLIST.TXT) DO ECHO %%i
```

But again, no output?  Any ideas?

[I've been through [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155932/449156) but can't find anything obvious)

Comment: Found the problem...the file is unicode - when it's a "real" file it could contain Arabic or English - which raises the question...who would I parse this?

Comment: Use VBScript or (better) PowerShell. Both of them are far better at handling Unicode than batch.

Comment: Would love to move to PS...but need time to learn it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('cmd /A /C type CIFLIST.TXT') DO ECHO %%i
```

Comment: That seems to work...will test again later with a fully unicode file (e.g. containing arabic)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('type CIFLIST.TXT') DO ECHO %%i
```