# How to find whether any checkin is made in clearcase for particular component since yesterday?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

In our project we are having multiple components.

If a component has changes [check in happened ] then that component should be taken for build.

How to find whether the component is changed since yesterday or not?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to make a baseline on that component, since ClearCase will refuse to make one if said UCM component has no change yet (see "[Creating an identical baseline in UCM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257603)").
But that would mean having to delete the baseline if you don't want to keep it around, and deleting a baseline can be time consuming.

The other way is to be able to find the most recent activity for a given stream, and [list the associated versions of that activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632818/6309) (checking for their date).
That works better if:

- you know in which streams those changes might occur for the component.
- you have a naming convention which makes getting the right activity immediate (instead of having to [list activities in a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563404/6309))