# put contents of a text file in commandline

Tags: batch-file, cmd

in a batch I have

```
echo VirtualDub.video.AddComment^(0x0000000C,"","%tc%"^)^;>>v:\automazioneclip\virtualdubmod\temp\%%~na.vcf
```

but now in place of %tc% I would like insert the contents of a text file, all content of a text file

How I have to modify it? thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple lines in the text file? Is it OK for a string in your function call to span multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

Use SET /P to print out the first portion of the line without a newline. Then use TYPE to print out the contents. Then finish up with a normal ECHO.

```
<nul (
  set /p ^"=VirtualDub.video.AddComment^(0x0000000C,"",""
  type file.txt
  (echo ^"^);)
) >>"v:\automazioneclip\virtualdubmod\temp\%%~na.vcf"
```

Note that the closing quote after the file contents will appear on the next line if the file ends with a newline. Obviously the value will be spread across multiple lines if the file contains multiple lines. Multiple lines may or may not be a problem depending on the language of the code you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Related question: [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

So possibly something like:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do [process] %%A
```

where "process" is your line above.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do echo VirtualDub.video.AddComment^(0x0000000C,"","%%A"^)^;>>v:\automazioneclip\virtualdubmod\temp\%%~na.vcf
```