# Windows batch script won't loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that is supposed to help me go find and copy a list of files to another folder. The list of files is in a .csv file separated with commas, for example `xyz123,abc456`. But the script only finds and copies the first file then stops.  Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't continue? Here's the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
set FIILELIST=C:\job\crcfilelist.txt
set FILESPATH=C:\filesource
set DESTPATH=C:\job\

for /f "delims=," %%x in (%FIILELIST%) do (forfiles /p %FILESPATH% /s /m %%x.* /c "cmd /c copy /y @path %DESTPATH%\@file" 2>>failed_temp.txt)

PAUSE
```

Note: I got this from another post on this forum but I can't remember where. Thanks to whoever wrote it.

Comment: You seem to have copied the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325529)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOR /F` will read the file and assign the `metavariable` (in this case, `%%x`) with the first "token" in the line (tokens are separated by the `delims` character-set).

Then it goes on to the next line and repeats.

Try

```
for /f "delims=" %%q in (csvfilename) do for %%x in (%%q) do ...
```

which will assign the entirety of the line from the file to `%%q` and since this is a comma-separated list, `%%x` will see a comma-separated list and happily execute your command using each comma-separated token.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation - or thousands of examples on SO.