# Iterate through text file with batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, dos

I would like to know how to loop through each line in a text file using a Windows batch file and process each line of text in succession. I have a text file containing filenames.

What I'd like to do is something like

```
for x in textFile
    "python C:\main.py -s x"  # the command i want to run
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what have you searched for? This is an extremely easy task in batch that has been documented... basically everywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%x in (textFilename) do python C:\main.py -s %%x
```

would be the classic method - as a batch file.

reduce `%%` to `%` throughout if you are running directly from the prompt

or, more fully,

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%x in ("textFilename") do python C:\main.py -s "%%x"
```

Comment: Don't forget to include `"delims="` to grab the entire line, and `"usebackq"` in case the file path has a space in it somewhere.