# Issues with variables when using EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 issues with my Batch file, I think they are due to `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

I am basing my script in [this post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163873/752842).

I need `EnableDelayedExpansion` for another part of my script, so I need to keep it.

This is my script:

```
@echo off
set myPath=Subfolder1
set folderList=input.txt
set originalPath=%~dp0  

cd %myPath%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:process

for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (%~dp0\%folderList%) do (
    echo Folder %%S
    REM echo Folder %%S prints: Folder folderName
    set testPath=C:\BatchTests\%%S\
    echo test path: %testPath%
    REM echo test path: %testPath% prints: test path:
)
echo %originalPath%
REM echo %originalPath% prints: C:\BatchTests\
cd %originalPath%
pause
```

`testPath` seems to be always empty, and the line `cd %originalPath%`.

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to use/set `testPath`?

[The second issue I am having is different, so I opened a separate question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484008/why-is-my-cd-myvar-being-ignored)

Comment: Try it with `!testPath!`

Comment: You do not need to store the working directory in a variable when using `pushd %myPath%` to change it temporarily and `popd` to restore the original one...

Comment: @jeb - That works! is that another way to use the variable?

Comment: @aschipfl - I didnt know that technique, but it doesnt work either :S

Comment: Supposing `Subfolder1` (stored in `%myPath%`) exists and is accessible, this does work; note that the batch file parent directory `%~dp0` and the current working directory are _not_ the same thing; to query the latter, use `%CD%`...

Comment: @Dzyann That is the point of using delayed expansion, exclamation mark expansion i enabled by `seltlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` see also `set /?`

Comment: @aschipfl - the pushd works, it moves to the new directory, but the popd doesnt, so it stays in the new directory.

Comment: @jeb - Thanks a lot! If you post that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Dzyann, `popd` _is_ restoring the former directory, but I just recognized that `setlocal` also stores the current directory; after the batch file finished execution, an implicit `endlocal` is done, so the most recent directory _before_ `setlocal` is restored... sorry for confusion!! so just put `cd %myPath%` down below `setlocal` and everything is fine...

Comment: @aschipfl - I realize now that both issues are different, so i posted a different question for the issue you addressed. If you post your answer there I will accept it. Thank you!: [my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484008/why-is-my-cd-myvar-being-ignored)

Comment: Alright, @Dzyann; feel free to accept the **best** answer there... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use delayed expansion in batch you need to parts.

First you have to enable it with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.
And then you can expand any variable with exclamation marks instead of percent signs.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=origin
(
  set var=New Value
  echo Percent: %var%
  echo delayed: !var!
)
```

The output is

> Percent: origin
>   delayed: New Value

Percent expansion is evaluated when a command or block is parsed.
Delayed expansion is evaluated when a command is executed.