# why is my cd %myVar% being ignored?

Tags: batch-file

I save my original path in `originalPath` and then move to another folder. At the end when I do `cd %originalPath%`, it doesn't work. It stays in the new path.

I have tried using `pushd %myPath%` and `popd`, but it doesn't work either.

`C:\BatchTests\` has my script and the folder `Subfolder1`.

My script:

```
@echo off
set myPath=Subfolder1
set folderList=input.txt
REM set originalPath=%CD%
set originalPath=%~dp0  

REM pushd %myPath%
cd %myPath%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:process

REM The rest of my script

echo %originalPath%
REM echo %originalPath% prints: C:\BatchTests\
cd %originalPath%
REM popd
pause
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Quoting unknown paths

Paths not known on running a batch file and not being fixed could contain 1 or more spaces. This means path strings should be quoted like file names.

### 2. Change drive and directory

Command **CD** changes by default the current directory on current drive only.

Option `/D` to change current directory to a directory on any drive with a letter should be always used when current directory on starting a batch file is not fixed on same drive as temporarily used current directory.

### 3. setlocal and endlocal save and restore also current directory

The command **setlocal** creates always a new copy of the environment table which is destroyed when using **endlocal** or exiting the batch file restoring previous table. Also the states of command extensions and delayed expansion is saved and restored. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360955/3074564) with an example demonstrating what happens on using **setlocal** and **endlocal**.

But additionally **setlocal** saves also current directory and **endlocal** restores it as the following code demonstrates.

```
@echo off
set "InitialPath=%CD%"
echo 1. Current directory is: %CD%
cd /D "%windir%\Temp"
echo 2. Current directory is: %CD%
setlocal
rem Change current directory to parent directory.
cd ..\
echo 3. Current directory is: %CD%
setlocal
rem Change current directory to root of current drive.
cd \
echo 4. Current directory is: %CD%
endlocal
echo 5. Current directory is: %CD%
endlocal
echo 6. Current directory is: %CD%
cd /D "%InitialPath%"
echo 7. Current directory is: %CD%
set "InitialPath="
pause
```

### 4. Trailing spaces and tabs assigned to environment variable

With not using double quotes on assigning a value to an environment variable, command **set** appends everything after first equal sign up to end of line to the environment variable including not visible trailing spaces and tabs. There are trailing spaces on line `set originalPath=%~dp0`  , see answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for more details.

---

Your code improved to avoid all the possible issues listed above:

```
@echo off
set "myPath=Subfolder1"
set "folderList=input.txt"
REM set "originalPath=%CD%"
set "originalPath=%~dp0"

REM pushd "%myPath%"
cd /D "%myPath%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:process
REM The rest of my script

endlocal
echo %originalPath%
REM echo %originalPath% prints: C:\BatchTests\
cd /D "%originalPath%"
REM popd
pause
```

And taking point 3 into account and as [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) also explained well, following would work, too.

```
@echo off
set "myPath=Subfolder1"
set "folderList=input.txt"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%myPath%"

:process
REM The rest of my script

endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does not really stay in the changed directory. The real problem is that `setlocal`, besides environment variable changes, caches the current directory, which you already changed by `cd %myPath%`.

Then you switch back to the former directory by `cd %originalPath%`. But as soon as the batch script finishes execution, an implicit `endlocal` occurs which resets the current directory to the one previously cached by `setlocal`.

The issue is exactly the same if you remove `REM` from the `pushd` and `popd` lines and comment out the `cd` lines instead.

To solve the problem, simply move the `cd %myPath%` line (or the `pushd` command) down below `setlocal`. Actually you do even not need to store the current directory initially when you change it only in between the `setlocal`/`endlocal` block (even if `endlocal` is not explicitly stated):

```
@echo off
set myPath=Subfolder1
set folderList=input.txt

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM pushd %myPath%
cd %myPath%

:process

REM The rest of my script

REM popd
pause
endlocal
```