# why cant I use cd to navigate to sd card in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, windows-10, sd-card

I have an sd card and I want to navigate cmd to it. But when I type: `cd D:\MyFolder`  then this is the output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd D:\MyFolder

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

he does not say that the path does not exist but also does not navigate to it. What is my problem? can I solve it?

Edit:

I have windows 10 newest version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is my cd %myVar% being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484008/why-is-my-cd-myvar-being-ignored)

Comment: No it did not answer my question

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484400/902497) says "Command CD changes by default the current directory on current drive only. Option /D to change current directory to a directory on any drive with a letter should be always used when current directory on starting a batch file is not fixed on same drive as temporarily used current directory."

Comment: and this was first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd /d D:\

D:\
```

because cd is the shortcut of **c**ange **d**ictory and not change drive and `/d` tells him to switch drive

and if you add this:

```
@cd /d %1
```

to a file called sd.bat (switch drive) what is placed in the folder C:\windows\system32 then you can just do:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sd ..\

C:\WINDOWS>sd D:\

D:>sd my-folder

D:\my-folder>
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you this is the solution i needed