# List files in a folder using command prompt (In text form!)

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how to make a batch file list files, but in text form, just as you would make it say hello world using the echo command. I don't want it to create another file, but if it is needed, I will create a folder for it.

Here is the command that will create a text file:

```
dir /b > filelist.txt
```

Comment: Why not create a file and read the file..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: what do you mean by : "but if it is needed, I will create a folder for it."

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the part redirecting to file, like this:

```
dir /b
```