# Literally echo the text "on"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

I'm writing a windows CMD Batch file, that (for simplified purposes) is supposed to echo every line of this file:

```
Flash
your
lights
on 
and
off
```

The problem is when it gets to the 4th and 6th words, it ends up running `echo on` and `echo off`, which does *not* actually echo the text, instead it just sets the state of echo to be ON and OFF.

```
for /F %%a in (DataFile.txt) do echo %%a
```

The resulting Output is:

```
Flash
your
lights
and
```

Is there a way to literally echo the text `on` and `off`?

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the %%a in quotes?

Comment: That just puts quotes around every word.  It then outputs `"on"` and `"off"`, but all the extra quotes are a new problem.

Comment: Use `echo(%%a` (this syntax looks odd but is the only secure way to `echo` every text, even `/?`, literally)...

Comment: @aschipfl:  That works!  Any reference or explanation why?  If you make that and answer, I will up-vote and accept.

Comment: Even with `echo(%%a` you have still problems with empty lines or lines beginning with `;`, they will be dropped. And when delayed expansion is enabled, then `!` and sometimes `^` carets will be dropped, too. A solution for both is the answer from Jonas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post on DosTips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774#p4554), the only safe way to echo any text is to use the odd-looking syntax `echo(`. So for your command line:

```
for /F %%a in (DataFile.txt) do echo(%%a
```

There is the syntax `echo.` commonly used, but this fails in case there is a file called `echo.` (no extension) in the current working directory.
The syntax `echo/` sometimes used fails if you try to echo a string starting with a question mark (because `/` followed by `?` is interpreted as the `/?` switch to display the help text for the command).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ %userprofile%\Desktop\DataFile.txt"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    echo(!var!
    ENDLOCAL
)
Pause
```

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file).

on and off, in the context of what you are doing won't work because they are what you call (reserved words in the language) They are used as `@echo off` or `@echo on`

The script I posted got around that minor problem. However my lack of of knowledge in batch forces me to conclude my answer as I have no idea of how the script does it.