# Script to Delete various files from different subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have thousands of files in 39 sub-folders. I do identify around 50 files to delete from sub-folders. I need batch script to delete them together.

Like,

Sub-Folder A Contain > a1,a2,a3,a4 //These all are file name including extension

Sub-Folder B Contain > b1,b2,b3

..........

Sub-Folder Z Contain > z1,z2,z3,z4,z5

I need to Delete,

a3

b1

c7

d5

z2

z4

Hope you can understand my problem.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there any criterion/pattern to identify the files? If not it's quite simple: one line of del <path>/<filename> for every file

Comment: I do a list of the files in text (.txt) format. Which file name are listed in .txt, those will be deleted.

Comment: This is a repeated task that's why a script should help me. But the names are unique in different path always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself able to create the script,

```
FOR /F "delims=#" %%j IN (list_of_to_be_deleted.txt) DO ( del /s %%j
echo %%j has been Deleted!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the files mentioned in your text file, you can perform a for loop like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=#" %%j IN (your_list.txt) DO ( echo %%j
del %%j
)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it just open the text file, nothing do

Comment: You need inverted commas around %%j (like "%%j") if your paths contain blanks. Can you post the output of the script?

Comment: Output, after changing with inverted commas just blinking the cmd screen for once. Not delete any file

Comment: add ``PAUSE`` at the end of the file in order to see what happens

Comment: with inverted comma, PAUSE not work it blinking!
Without comma:
D:\Backup>FOR /F "delims=#" %j IN ('Junk.txt') DO (
echo %j
 del %j

Comment: is the script started from the path in which Junk.txt resides? Maybe try first with a script that only contains one line with ``type Junk.txt`` and another one with ``PAUSE``. If the content of Junk.txt is not shown on the screen, the path is wrong!

Comment: .bat file & Junk.txt (list of file to be deleted) reside in same path, this path (root folder) also contains all sub-folders. Tried with one line .txt, it just open the text file but not the content (file which will be deleted)

Comment: Does it show the content of the text file? What else does it show?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) one can obmit the TYPE command, so I updated my solution. if you remove the DEL statement and keep the PAUSE at the end: Do you see the filenames of the files to delete?

Comment: Now it different in result: 
'C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Backup>(
echo QSMTEX
 del QSMTEX
)
QSMTEX
Could Not Find C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Backup\QSMTEX'