# Create Batch Script to Scan Multiple Files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, findstr

I'm looking to make a batch script. What I have is a ton of different logs in a ton of different places, all with a bit of important info and a lot of useless info.

Some of these logs are directly named, and some are named by date and time.

I'm trying to make a script that can basically scan them for me so I don't have to go through each folder and log and scan manually.

Some examples:

- OmegaManager\logs\omega.log - scan for "State:" and "has been updated"
- OmegaManager\logs\instance-0.log - scan for "shutdown"
- KRBanking\PlayerDatabase*logs are numbers* - copy all information or scan for changes since last time?
- KRBanking\ServerLogs*logs are dates and times* - scan for "Deposited" and "Withdrawed"

And then output the whole line.

Is this even moderately possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could use a [for loop to go over the directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138497/iterate-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-for-loop) and use [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) to search for patterns of text in files.

Please share your code if you have already tried something. SO is not a coding service, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks. I asked if it was possible and it seems like it is using findstr. Can you direct me somewhere to a coding service because that's all I see on here so I'm sorry I didn't catch the memo.

I don't know batch scripting at all so everything I find is the same chart of info over and over again but I'm not getting anywhere. I would LOVE to do it myself but I need a lot of help then.

Comment: It's fun to learn to write batch files, you can automate so much. See my answer below for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Batch files support loops, conditions, and filtering/searching.

A FOR loop allows you to iterate through files or directories, you'll find more information [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file).

To find strings in a file, you have several options, i.e. find and findstr, see [riptutorial.com](https:///batch-file/example/19477/basic-strings-search):

- FIND can scan large files line-by-line to find a certain string with no wildcard support.
- FINDSTR has more features and supports regular expressions with wildcards in the search string.

#### Super simple example for one of your use cases

The batch script must be placed where your files are. Otherwise, you need to  add a full path instead of just "omega.log".

```
FINDSTR /L /C:"State:" /C:"has been updated" omega.log
```

To start with batch programming, you can read the [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) documentation and some tutorials.